# module import outside index.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I'm trying to create a project and I want to use my firebase database inside a page which is not index.html (the file called abc.html) when I'm importing firebase/app I get an error in the console which is:

> abc.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMfwZ.png)

Please if you need anything else do tell. I guess it's a simple problem but I'm new to this and I still need your help

abc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hello
</body>
<script type="module">import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";</script>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

abc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hello
</body>
<script type="module">import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";</script>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coupons-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Up up up up up up